# How to generate Hash160 from a private key with the Bitcoin module

Tags: private-key, public-key, bitcoin-core-development, python, pybitcointools

I want to fix the script code. The script generates from a random private key Bitcoin Address by function **(pubtoaddr)** and works
on the Bitcoin module:

https://github.com/primal100/pybitcointools/blob/master/cryptos/main.py

```
from bitcoin import *
import os

    priv = random_key ()
    pub = privtopub (priv)
    addr = pubtoaddr (pub)

....
....
```

But I need to get from a **Random Private Key** in **Hash160**

For some reason I could not find such a function in **main.py**

I searched and found an [article](https://whatdoesthequantsay.com/2014/05/04/bitcoin-transactions-technically-part-2)

```
>>> import pybitcointools
>>> privkey = pybitcointools.random_key ()
>>> privkey
'34030ce14e32ac982419b3683af3b59d64a29cc93798cf479d610af49d425d13'
>>> pubkey = pybitcointools.privtopub (privkey)
>>> pubkey
'04ce0ed35340803b0c21f2f7f5d5ab9d687e5fa95a79471c9b5c9d97a0bb170eac1045230cc51d13b85a5f64feb80f8fc19358a396797926e3f89d49066b1abc07'
>>> h160 = pybitcointools.hash160 (pubkey.decode ('hex'))
>>> h160
'1558c7cd9825447a31990ff964f347bb2dbfe9be'
>>> addr = pybitcointools.hex_to_b58check (h160)
>>> addr
'12wsYc4B9c9JeREqstLZXNWa3n4i42M5jg'
```

Unfortunately I could not get from

```
 priv = random_key ()  --- > Hash160
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am using a different [bitcoin library](https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils). This prints address and hash160 from a private key:

```
from bitcoinutils.setup import setup
from bitcoinutils.keys import P2pkhAddress, PrivateKey, PublicKey

def main():
    # setup the network
    setup('testnet')

    # provide a private WIF key
    priv = PrivateKey.from_wif('cMahea7zqjxrtgAbB7LSGbcQUr1uX1ojuat9jZodMN87K7XCyj5v')

    # get the public key
    pub = priv.get_public_key()


    # get address from public key
    address = pub.get_address()


    # print address and hash160
    print("Address:", address.to_string())
    print("Hash160:", address.to_hash160())

    print("\n--------------------------------------\n")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: python-output]

For segwit addresses you can refer to this example: https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils/blob/master/examples/keys_segwit_addresses.py

Comment: I'll try to use this module! How to write a function in the code so that "PrivateKey" is generated in a random way?

Comment: Replace `priv = PrivateKey.from_wif('cMahea7zqjxrtgAbB7LSGbcQUr1uX1ojuat9jZodMN87K7XCyj5v')` with `priv = PrivateKey()` in the above code and also add a print statement below to see the new private key each time you run the code: `print("Private Key:", priv.to_wif(compressed=True))`

Comment: Can I use the HEX format here?

Comment: If you are asking about private key WIF, it's base58: https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/wif

Comment: IDK if the P2PKH address is good, probably because I can see the Testnet 'm' prefix. Maybe verify the checksum. That's a good point. AFAIK, if you want know all details to transform a private key in an address, you can have a look at http://royalforkblog.github.io/2014/08/11/graphical-address-generator/. However, it's a valid answer I think.

Answer (score 0):

I find the Bit module the easiest and most straight forward, albeit a tad, limited but with bit you can simply:

```py
from bit import Key

# To generate private key
privKey= Key()

# Create Ripemd-160 Hash (address)
privKey.address

# or 

myAddress = privKey.address

# Segwit

MySegwitAddress = privKey.segwit_address
```

You can also import your own existing private keys like so:

```py
# For wif format:
privKey = Key.('L1VotKmtZRLZSnSPhLhQxfts2aqBMru2APTs4Yuc8TYJ4jNhQoGB')

# For hex format:

privKey = Key.from_hex('ccb8c423403f4d5b6cde505d2a8f39d1d9399f6e06853339f5b11593cc502dc9')

# For int format:

privKey = Key.from_int('92598274663553697917256765988661195316245391320286084491562671024534692310473')

# For bytes format
privKey = Key.from_der(b'\xcc\xb8\xc4#@?M[l\xdeP]*\x8f9\xd1\xd99\x9fn\x06\x8539\xf5\xb1\x15\x93\xccP-\xc9)
```

Exporting works pretty much the same way as importing except you replace `from.[format here]` with `to.[format here]`, you can even import or export a PEM file of your private key.

The documentation is enough for the library to give you the core functions, but is also somewhat lacking, for example you can't create compressed bitcoin addresses. But otherwise you can sign, send transactions, even select exactly which outputs you want to use .etc